# how to write .npy file to s3 directly?

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3

I would like to know if there is any way to write an array as a numpy file(.npy) to an AWS S3 bucket directly. I can use `np.save` to save a file locally as shown below. But I am looking for a solution to write it directly to S3, without saving locally first.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
np.save('/my/localfolder/test1.npy', a)
```

Comment: Did you search for "Numpy save to s3"? Did you not see this for example? https://github.com/gallantlab/cottoncandy/blob/master/README.md

Comment: can i use that library within a for loop to write and save multiple .npy files ? for instance ,where the filenames are appended by their respective loop index.

Comment: That library doesn't care about loops, so yes, probably

Comment: @cricket_007 where to specify directory name in the above library ? I didn't find any way to upload them to  a specific directory ?

Comment: @dks551 directories don't exist in S3. The entire file name can include backslash like paths

Comment: @cricket_007 I used this library inside a spark map function and its throwing me error "pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects"

Comment: Please edit your question to mention you're using Spark and the code you wrote plus the full error you're getting

Answer (score 6):

If you want to bypass your local disk and upload directly the data to the cloud, you may want to use `pickle` instead of using a `.npy` file:

```py
import boto3
import io
import pickle

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

my_array = numpy.random.randn(10)

# upload without using disk
my_array_data = io.BytesIO()
pickle.dump(my_array, my_array_data)
my_array_data.seek(0)
s3_client.upload_fileobj(my_array_data, 'your-bucket', 'your-file.pkl')

# download without using disk
my_array_data2 = io.BytesIO()
s3_client.download_fileobj('your-bucket', 'your-file.pkl', my_array_data2)
my_array_data2.seek(0)
my_array2 = pickle.load(my_array_data2)

# check that everything is correct
numpy.allclose(my_array, my_array2)
```

Documentation:

- [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj)
- [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump)
- [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)

Comment: This works for me, though I've also heard that using *s3_client.put_object()* is specifically designed for this (rather than *s3_client.upload_fileobj()*). In this answer, @M1L0U, is the data being doubled in memory by using the BytesIO object?

Comment: I would just change the _pickling_ part to use numpy's own methods: `np.save(my_array_data, my_array, allow_pickle=True)` and `np.load(my_array_data2, allow_pickle=True)`

Comment: @alex but the np.save will write it to disk, which is explicitly not want the OP wants

Comment: @user1725306 you can use [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead of a file

Answer (score 4):

I've recently had issues with s3fs dependency conflicts with boto3, so I try to avoid using it. This solution only depends on boto3, does not write to disk, and does not explicitly use pickle.

Saving:

```py
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import boto3
client = boto3.client("s3")

def to_s3_npy(data: np.array, s3_uri: str):
    # s3_uri looks like f"s3://{BUCKET_NAME}/{KEY}"
    bytes_ = BytesIO()
    np.save(bytes_, data, allow_pickle=True)
    bytes_.seek(0)
    parsed_s3 = urlparse(s3_uri)
    client.upload_fileobj(
        Fileobj=bytes_, Bucket=parsed_s3.netloc, Key=parsed_s3.path[1:]
    )
    return True
```

Loading:

```py
def from_s3_npy(s3_uri: str):
    bytes_ = BytesIO()
    parsed_s3 = urlparse(s3_uri)
    client.download_fileobj(
        Fileobj=bytes_, Bucket=parsed_s3.netloc, Key=parsed_s3.path[1:]
    )
    bytes_.seek(0)
    return np.load(bytes_, allow_pickle=True)
```

Comment: is there any solution without using boto3?

Comment: I don't think so unless you want to write your own interface to AWS. `boto3` is the defacto python SDK for AWS services and other libraries like `s3fs` just wrap it.

Comment: I don't want to write my own interface but I need to implement it in micropython... hence was looking for a method without using boto3. I am trying to work on a microcontroller...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is a file system interface to s3, a wrapper around `boto`. This solution also uses pickle, so make sure to `allow_pickle=True` at `np.load`. Refer functions below to both write and read.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
from s3fs.core import S3FileSystem
s3 = S3FileSystem()

def saveLabelsToS3(npyArray, name):
    with s3.open('{}/{}'.format(bucket, name), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(npyArray))

def readLabelsFromS3(name):
    return np.load(s3.open('{}/{}'.format(bucket, name)), allow_pickle=True)

# Use as below
saveLabelsToS3(labels, 'folder/filename.pkl')
labels = readLabelsFromS3('folder/filename.pkl')
```